# Limit involving Heaviside step function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $F(x) = (1-x^2) (H(x+1) -H(x-1))$. Let $g$ be a continuous function on the interval $[-1, 1]$. Find $$ \text{lim} _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ \frac{3}{4} \int_{-1}^1 nF(nx)g(x) \ \text{dx}$$

$H(x)$ is Heaviside step function.

I think that limit would be $g(0)$. But I can not prove it. Please help me.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch:** Observe that
\begin{align}
H(x+1)-H(x-1) = \chi_{[-1, 1]}(x)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
F(nx) = (1-n^2 x^2)\chi_{[-1, 1]}(n x) = (1-n^2x^2)\chi_{[-1/n, 1/n]}(x).
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\int^1_{-1}nF(nx)g(x) dx = \int^{1/n}_{-1/n}n(1-n^2 x^2)g(x)\ dx  = \int^1_{-1} (1-z^2) g(\frac{z}{n})\ d z.
\end{align}
Hence it follows that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{4}\int^1_{-1}(1-z^2)g(z/n) dz = \frac{3}{4}g(0) \int^1_{-1}(1-z^2)dz = g(0). 
\end{align}

I will let you fill out the rigorous detail about the interchanging of limit and integration.